# in python 2.6 how do i change a global variable within a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, global-variables, python-2.x

i want to change the value of a variable within a for loop, but then have the new preserved variable changed when the loop finishes

my attempt (kinda simplified from what i'm actually doing)

SNP is a list and compar_1 is a list of lists

```
line_1 = empty_row
for SNP1 in compar_1:
    global line_1
    if SNP[3] == SNP1[3] 
        compare_line_1 = SNP1 
print = line_1
output_file.write(to_print)
```

if it finds a match within the loop i want it to change the variable to that so that's what's printed, if it doesn't find a match in the for loop i want it to print the "empty_row" (a string defined earlier)

Comment: It's a little hard to see what you are saying... you can assign the variable within a loop, just like you would outside of it.

Comment: Can you post your post inside the original question? (Use the `edit` link.)

Comment: this is far from valid python, could you post your actual code?

Comment: full code too long, i think i've worked out my problem now

Answer (score 3):

If you had tried to just change the variable, you would have seen that it just works. Python does not have separate scope for loops.

Comment: ah... i was wondering about that a while ago and couldn't find a definitive answer so i've been running on the opposite assumption, i'll take it out and test it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops do not affect variable scope in Python (like they could in C)

If you were using variables inside a function, you can use [`global [var]`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) to declare that when you refer to `[var]` that you mean the global one.

[This](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/) is a decent overview of scope in Python

Comment: see other comment re scope, and thanks

i was thinking maybe it would get re-defined in subsequent iterations, but if it only changes when that if condition is met it shouldn't be affected by subsequent iteration at all...

Answer (score 0):

```
for SNP1 in compar_1:
    if SNP[3] == SNP1[3]:
        line_1 = SNP1 
        break
else:
    line_1 = empty_row
to_print = line_1
output_file.write(to_print)
```

Comment: that looks more elegant than mine, but doesn't the else need to be in line with the if? it looks a bit odd.

Comment: The `else` belongs to the `for`, not the `if`. If the loop does not do at least one iteration, the `else` block is executed.

Comment: yeah i wondered if that could be it, but couldn't work out how a for could have an else, does it relate to the break?

Comment: It does indeed relate to the break, essentially the else of a for loop is executed if the loop terminates naturally (that is not by a break). So in your example if the expression "if SNP[3] == SNP1[3]" never evaluates to true the else will be executed.